# Minimum jerk trajectory with CVXPY

Tags: mathematical-optimization, convex-optimization, cvxpy

I am trying to numerically solve the problem of generating a 1D minimum jerk trajectory using cvxpy (version 0.4.9). Here is the basic statement of the problem,

[image]

'x' is the vector of position as a function of time. 'D' is the matrix for calculating the jerk, 'A' and 'b' specify the the constraints for position, velocity and acceleration. x[0] = 0, and x[N] = 1. The velocity and acceleration start and end at 0.

I tried to solve this problem using CVXPY using using the following code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.linalg import toeplitz
from scipy.linalg import block_diag
import cvxpy as cvx  # Version 0.4.9

# setup sample rate
N = 1000 # number of samples

# set up jerk matrix D
_row = np.hstack((np.array([[-1, 3, -3, 1]]), np.zeros((1,N-4))))
_col = np.vstack((np.array([[-1]]), np.zeros((N-4,1))))
D = toeplitz(_col, _row)

# set up constraint A*x = b
pos_i = np.hstack((np.array([[1]]), np.zeros((1,N-1))))
pos_f = np.hstack((np.zeros((1,N-1)), np.array([[1]])))

vel_i = np.hstack((np.array([[-1, 1]]), np.zeros((1,N-2))))
vel_f = np.hstack((np.zeros((1,N-2)), np.array([[-1, 1]])))

accl_i = np.hstack((np.array([[1,-2,1]]), np.zeros((1,N-3))))
accl_f = np.hstack((np.zeros((1,N-3)), np.array([[1,-2,1]])))

A = np.vstack((pos_i, pos_f, 
               vel_i, vel_f,
               accl_i, accl_f))
b = np.zeros((6,1))
b[0] = 0
b[1] = 1

# Construct the problem.
x = cvx.Variable(N)
objective = cvx.Minimize(cvx.sum_squares(1000 * D * x))
constraints = [A * x == b]
prob = cvx.Problem(objective, constraints)

# The optimal objective is returned by prob.solve().
result = prob.solve(verbose=True)

print("Problem status: {0}".format(prob.status))

pos = x.value[:, 0]
vel = 10 * np.diff(pos, axis=0)
accl = 10 * np.diff(vel, axis=0)
jerk = 10 * np.diff(accl, axis=0)

plt.subplot(221)
plt.plot(pos)
plt.title('Position')
plt.subplot(222)
plt.plot(vel)
plt.title('Velocity')
plt.subplot(223)
plt.plot(accl)
plt.title('Acceleration')
plt.subplot(224)
plt.plot(jerk)
plt.title('Jerk')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I get the following output, as expected, when **N = 100**.

```
ECOS 2.0.4 - (C) embotech GmbH, Zurich Switzerland, 2012-15. Web: www.embotech.com/ECOS

It     pcost       dcost      gap   pres   dres    k/t    mu     step   sigma     IR    |   BT
 0  +0.000e+00  -1.329e-04  +4e+03  3e-02  5e-06  1e+00  2e+03    ---    ---    1  1  - |  -  - 
 1  -1.866e-01  -9.469e-05  +4e+01  3e-04  5e-08  2e-01  2e+01  0.9890  1e-04   1  1  1 |  0  0
 2  -4.287e-03  -1.687e-05  +5e-01  3e-06  7e-10  4e-03  2e-01  0.9882  1e-04   2  2  2 |  0  0
 3  +2.401e-03  +3.685e-03  +7e-02  4e-07  1e-10  1e-03  4e-02  0.8562  3e-03   3  4  4 |  0  0
 4  +3.743e-02  +4.859e-02  +3e-01  3e-06  4e-11  1e-02  1e-01  0.9890  3e-01   7  9  9 |  0  0
 5  -2.330e-01  -1.977e-01  +4e-01  1e-06  1e-10  4e-02  2e-01  0.4759  6e-01   1  1  1 |  0  0
 6  +3.801e-03  +1.396e-02  +2e-01  5e-07  2e-11  1e-02  9e-02  0.9890  9e-02   1  1  1 |  0  0
 7  +5.710e-02  +5.937e-02  +4e-02  7e-07  4e-12  2e-03  2e-02  0.9890  4e-02   1  1  1 |  0  0
 8  +7.743e-02  +7.747e-02  +1e-03  3e-07  9e-12  5e-05  6e-04  0.9890  1e-03   8  9  9 |  0  0
 9  +8.119e-02  +8.124e-02  +4e-04  3e-07  8e-12  5e-05  2e-04  0.9095  1e-01   8  9  9 |  0  0
10  +8.086e-02  +8.094e-02  +1e-03  1e-07  5e-12  8e-05  6e-04  0.8810  5e-01   6  7  6 |  0  0
11  +8.263e-02  +8.267e-02  +1e-04  2e-07  4e-12  4e-05  8e-05  0.9890  9e-02   8  9  9 |  0  0
12  +8.323e-02  +8.324e-02  +2e-04  1e-07  3e-12  1e-05  9e-05  0.9890  2e-01   8  9  9 |  0  0
13  +8.354e-02  +8.355e-02  +6e-05  7e-08  2e-12  7e-06  4e-05  0.9890  1e-01   8  9  9 |  0  0
14  +8.375e-02  +8.375e-02  +2e-05  6e-08  2e-12  3e-06  1e-05  0.9535  1e-01   8  9  9 |  0  0
15  +8.374e-02  +8.374e-02  +5e-05  3e-08  1e-12  4e-06  3e-05  0.8755  4e-01   6  7  6 |  0  0
16  +8.383e-02  +8.383e-02  +6e-06  3e-08  1e-12  2e-06  4e-06  0.9890  9e-02   9  9  9 |  0  0
17  +8.385e-02  +8.385e-02  +8e-06  3e-08  8e-13  6e-07  4e-06  0.9890  2e-01   8  9  9 |  0  0
18  +8.387e-02  +8.387e-02  +2e-06  2e-08  6e-13  3e-07  1e-06  0.9890  8e-02   8  8  8 |  0  0
19  +8.388e-02  +8.388e-02  +1e-06  1e-08  4e-13  1e-07  8e-07  0.9890  1e-01   8  8  8 |  0  0
20  +8.388e-02  +8.388e-02  +6e-07  8e-09  3e-13  7e-08  4e-07  0.9890  1e-01   8  8  8 |  0  0
21  +8.389e-02  +8.389e-02  +3e-07  6e-09  2e-13  3e-08  2e-07  0.9890  1e-01   8  8  8 |  0  0
22  +8.389e-02  +8.389e-02  +2e-07  4e-09  1e-13  2e-08  1e-07  0.9890  2e-01   8  7  7 |  0  0
23  +8.389e-02  +8.389e-02  +5e-08  3e-09  1e-13  8e-09  3e-08  0.9786  9e-02   8  8  8 |  0  0
24  +8.389e-02  +8.389e-02  +1e-07  2e-09  6e-14  1e-08  7e-08  0.8905  4e-01   6  6  5 |  0  0
25  +8.389e-02  +8.389e-02  +1e-08  2e-09  6e-14  5e-09  1e-08  0.9890  1e-01   9  8  8 |  0  0
26  +8.389e-02  +8.389e-02  +3e-08  1e-09  4e-14  2e-09  1e-08  0.9890  3e-01   8  7  7 |  0  0
27  +8.389e-02  +8.389e-02  +5e-09  1e-09  3e-14  8e-10  3e-09  0.9890  7e-02   8  7  7 |  0  0

OPTIMAL (within feastol=1.0e-09, reltol=6.5e-08, abstol=5.5e-09).
Runtime: 0.006165 seconds.

Problem status: optimal
```

[image]

However, when I change **N = 1000**, I get something strange (problem status is still optimal).

```
ECOS 2.0.4 - (C) embotech GmbH, Zurich Switzerland, 2012-15. Web: www.embotech.com/ECOS

It     pcost       dcost      gap   pres   dres    k/t    mu     step   sigma     IR    |   BT
 0  +0.000e+00  -1.295e-05  +4e+04  5e-02  4e-06  1e+00  2e+04    ---    ---    1  1  - |  -  - 
 1  -1.911e+00  -3.203e-05  +4e+02  6e-04  5e-08  2e+00  2e+02  0.9890  1e-04   1  1  1 |  0  0
 2  -4.228e-02  -5.084e-05  +5e+00  5e-06  5e-10  4e-02  2e+00  0.9890  1e-04   2  2  2 |  0  0
 3  -7.419e-04  -4.283e-05  +5e-02  5e-08  2e-11  7e-04  3e-02  0.9890  1e-04   3  5  5 |  0  0
 4  +1.401e-06  +1.169e-05  +6e-04  2e-08  1e-11  1e-05  3e-04  0.9890  1e-04   6  9  9 |  0  0
 5  +1.029e-05  +1.043e-05  +6e-06  1e-08  8e-12  1e-07  3e-06  0.9890  1e-04   4  6  6 |  0  0
 6  +8.446e-06  +8.448e-06  +1e-07  8e-09  7e-12  2e-09  6e-08  0.9890  1e-04   5  6  6 |  0  0
 7  +7.053e-06  +7.053e-06  +6e-09  7e-09  6e-12  7e-11  3e-09  0.9890  1e-03   5  5  5 |  0  0

OPTIMAL (within feastol=7.3e-09, reltol=8.0e-04, abstol=5.7e-09).
Runtime: 0.011601 seconds.

Problem status: optimal
```

[image]

Why do I see a difference like this? What am I doing wrong and what should I do to fix this?

When I scale D by a factor of 1000, my results are different.

Comment: Make your code reproducible (imports) and tell us which version of cvxpy you are using. For a start: never trust the result without checking the status. Do ```prob.solve(verbose=True)``` (optional; good idea) and especially ```print(prob.status)``` after solving. I can imagine some source of the problem, but i usually prefer to be able to run the code.

Comment: @sascha Thanks for the comment. I have modified the question with all the details you requested. I hope this makes it more reproducible.

Comment: Okay sorry, this is not what i expected. I indeed expected the solver to fail because of numerical-issues and therefore you observe something unexpected. Now it should be clear that this problem is solely based on your model and i'm not experienced with these kind of models and it also feels the explanation might be a bit sparse (depending on background knowledge). The only thing, not addressing your issue, but maybe worthwhile some day: this problem looks like there is a [closed-form solution](https://see.stanford.edu/materials/lsoeldsee263/08-min-norm.pdf). See the ```LS``` solver in cvxpy

Answer (score 1):

This problem has a closed form solution.
See:

- [Linear Least Square Optimization with Linear Equality Constraints](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/724697).
- [Linear Least Squares with Linear Equality Constraints](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3610608).

You'll be able to solve it iteratively as well in case the matrices are big.

I think using the closed form solution will yield a better numerical stability for your case.